# Sequential processing within a partition in hazelcast jet

Tags: hazelcast-jet

Within a partition, does jet process each item sequentially, and/or is there a setting to config that way?

Thanks
Shannon

Comment: There are no specified rules about this. What is your underlying goal?

Comment: What partition do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each source processor processes items in one external partition sequentially. For example, each Kafka partition is assigned to single processor instance, and the processor emits the data sequentially.

However, if a downstream processor takes items from multiple upstream processors, the order is unspecified. However, items from one upstream processor can never be reordered.

Example: let's have two vertices, *A* and *B*. *A* has two instances: *A1*, *A2*; *B* has only one instance *B1*. If *A1* emits items *I1* and *I2* and *A2* emits *I3* and *I4*, *B1* can receive them in any this order, but it can never receive *I2* before *I1* or *I4* before *I3*. For example *I3*, *I1*, *I2*, *I4* is possible order, but *I2*, *I1*, *I3*, *I4* is not.

Sequential order between two vertices will be kept in these cases:

- both have equal local parallelism and [`Edge.isolated()`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/core/Edge.html#isolated--) is used.
- both are connected to their upstream processor with partitioned edge, use the same key, have equal parallelism and both are either distributed or both are not distributed.

Note that in these cases the downstream processor always has one upstream processor.

Also have a look at this image (taken from [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.5.1/manual/Under_the_Hood/How_Distributed_Computing_Works_in_Jet.html)). Two *Tokenize* circles are two processor instances of *Tokenize* vertex.

[image]